# Alphabetize by the *zeroth* letter

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

> No, you were supposed to alphabetize by the *zeroth* letter!
>
> [image]

---

The answer is a three-letter word.

Apologies that the answer is not more thematic; it made more sense in the context I originally used this puzzle. Also apologies that parts of the puzzle are a bit US-centric.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "zeroth" letter of each word is a letter that can be prefixed to make another word. Each of the words given has a different prefix:

> **e**Bay, **X**-files, **U**-haul, **V**-neck, **C**-section, **Q**-tip
>
> **U**-boat, **e**Book, **Y** Combinator, **D**-day, **G**-force, **K**-mart, **T**-mobile, **i**Pod, **O**-ring, **A**-team

If you then rearrange the rows and columns so that the prefixed words are in alphabetical order, you get a bitmap that spells "SeT".

[image]

Comment: What a speedrun! Maybe there's many eyes, or maybe it's just Joe Z.

Comment: There are definitely many eyes. Often I get to a question that's been open for 15 minutes only to find that somebody else has already given the correct answer.

Comment: Anyway, I rearranged them from left-to-right and top-to-bottom, but there's no discernible pattern...?

Comment: Unfortunately, some of the answers are less unique than I want.

Comment: Yeah, it was O-ring and V-neck.

Comment: @JoeZ. I've got an image with the bitmap. Do you want me to add it in?

Comment: @DennisMeng Sure thing.

Comment: Okay, I just put it in the suggested edit